# Regex matching all text following any of the predefined prefixes

Tags: regex

Example: parsing the source string

> **with** `apples, pears` **excluding** `kiwis`, **without** `oranges, grapefruits`, **including** `bananas`

with a working version of `(?:(?<in>with\b|included)|(?<out>without|excluded))(.+?)`
would produce matches with the following groups:

- in: [`apples, pears`, `bananas`]
- out: [`oranges, grapefruits`, `kiwis`]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please provide us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Consider passing us a URL with your example from a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com) which will provide a history of edits that we can assist you with. Please edit your question rather than adding comments. Also, there is `regex` and there is `regex`. Are you implementing this in a particular language? Thanks!

Comment: Regex is a bad fit for this type of parsing.

Comment: [Something like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cin%3ewith%5cb%7cinclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%29%7c%28%3f%3cout%3ewithout%7cexclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%29%29%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!with%28%3f%3aout%29%3f%7cexclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%7cinclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%29.%29%2b%29&i=with+apples%2c+pears+excluding+kiwis%2c+without+oranges%2c+grapefruits%2c+including+bananas) or...

Comment: [This one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cin%3ewith%5cb%7cinclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%29%7c%28%3f%3cout%3eexclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%7cwithout%29%29%5cs%2b%5cb%28%3f!with%28%3f%3aout%29%3f%7cexclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%7cinclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%29%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs*%2c%5cs*%28%3f!with%28%3f%3aout%29%3f%7cexclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%7cinclud%28%3f%3aed%7cing%29%29%5cw%2b%29*%5cb&i=with+apples%2c+pears+excluding+kiwis%2c+without+oranges%2c+grapefruits%2c+including+bananas).

Comment: Thanks, guys! @WiktorStribiżew, the first version is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @xberg: Please consider accepting the answer then.

Comment: @KennethK., this is just a simplified example bearing about 10% of the lexical complexity of the original task. IMHO, anything other than regex or a lexer (which would be an overshot in this case) would be a nightmare in terms of cyclomatic complexity of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:(?<in>with\b|includ(?:ed|ing))|(?<out>without|exclud(?:ed|ing)))((?:(?!with(?:out)?|exclud(?:ed|ing)|includ(?:ed|ing)).)+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cin%3Ewith%5Cb%7Cinclud%28%3F%3Aed%7Cing%29%29%7C%28%3F%3Cout%3Ewithout%7Cexclud%28%3F%3Aed%7Cing%29%29%29%28%28%3F%3A%28%3F!with%28%3F%3Aout%29%3F%7Cexclud%28%3F%3Aed%7Cing%29%7Cinclud%28%3F%3Aed%7Cing%29%29.%29%2B%29&i=with%20apples%2C%20pears%20excluding%20kiwis%2C%20without%20oranges%2C%20grapefruits%2C%20including%20bananas):

[image]

**Details**:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing grouping construct

  - `(?<in>with\b|includ(?:ed|ing))` - "in" group: `with` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary) or `included` / `including`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<out>without|exclud(?:ed|ing))` - "out" group: `without`, `excluded` / `excluding`
- `)` - end of the grouping
- `((?:(?!with(?:out)?|exclud(?:ed|ing)|includ(?:ed|ing)).)+)` - Capture group 1 matching any char (`.`), one or more times (`+`), that does not start any of the sequences inside the negative lookahead (`with`, `without`, `excluded` / `excluding`, `included` / `including`)